# Метод add в собственной коллекции

Tags: java

Размер коллекции после инициализации меняться не может. После того как количество элементов достигло максимума-при добавлении нового элемента коллекция сдвигается влево

```
public class MyColT  extends ArrayList{
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;
private Object[] elementData= {};
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
private int defaultCapacity;
private int valuecapacity;
private int size;

public MyColT() {
    this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
}

public MyColT(int valuecapacity) {
    if (valuecapacity > 0) {
        this.elementData = new Object[valuecapacity];

    } else if (valuecapacity == 0) {
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                valuecapacity);
    }
}


public MyColT(Collection c) {
    super(c);
}

@Override
public boolean add(Object o){
        if ((indexOf(o)) > valuecapacity) {
            remove(0);
            }


        return super.add(o);

}

public Object remove(int index) {
    return super.remove(index);
}
```

}

Comment: В чем вопрос? И почему в коллекцию размер которой не изменяется добавляются элементы?

Comment: Вопрос как реализовать метод чтобы после инициализации коллекции размер оставался неизменным. А в методе add добавить условие для удаления

Comment: С чем именно возникли сложности? О какой коллекции идет речь: список, множество, сопоставление, дерево? Приведите примеры ожидаемого поведения коллекции.

Comment: Вообще необходимо реализовать свою коллекцию, которая имеет фиксированный размер. Размер задается:по умолчанию 16 или по указанию пользователя. Каждый новый элемент добавляется в конец коллекции. Вот я решил так наследовать от ArrayList  и переопределить метод add.

Comment: Вы что-нибудь уже реализовали? Покажите код, а то неясно как коллекция должна себя вести.

Comment: Ну тут все просто, надо удалять Объект по нулевому индексу и делать Add, а коллекция сама влево уйдет. У вас почти получилось.

Comment: Просто не могу понять как тогда сделать  его неизменным после инициализации?